# Find $\frac{dG}{dx}$ of $G(x)=\int_0^{x^2}\frac{dt}{t^2+4}.$

Tags: calculus, integration

Define 
$$G(x)=\int_0^{x^2}\frac{dt}{t^2+4}.$$
What is $\displaystyle\frac{dG}{dx}$?

How do I approach this question?

What are the steps?

What is the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first equality below uses the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. The chain rule is used accordingly.
\begin{align}
\frac{dG}{dx} = \frac{1}{(x^2)^2+4} \cdot \frac{d}{dx}x^2=\frac{2x}{x^4+4}
\end{align}

Answer (score 4):

**HINT**

Use the [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus Part 1](http://math.ucsd.edu/~wgarner/math20b/ftc.htm) which states

$$\frac{d}{dx} \int^{h(x)}_{g(x)} f(t) \, dt = f(h(x))\cdot h'(x) - f(g(x))\cdot g'(x)$$

**HINT 2**

> $g(x) = 0$ and $h(x) = x^2$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use the Chain Rule and the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.